# Way to test more data without advancing pointer?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to check end-of-file on a recordset returned from MySQL (in PHP)?

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
while (!mysql_eof($result) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

I don't want to use mysql_fetch_array() in the main loop, because I need to do further reads inside the loop and don't want the recordset current record counter updated ie. I do not want to advance the current pointer.

Comment: [The mysql_ extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: [Consider checking one of the below answers as the right answer if they resolve your issue, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$counter = 1;
while($counter<=$num_rows)
{ 
//There is still more data
//Do whatever to the current row
$counter++;
}
```

Hope this does it. If not, I don't know what will.

Comment: I know I can do a fetch array, the question is: is there a way to check for more data without advancing the recordset.

Comment: LOL updating the database structure to deal with a simple EOF function is a bizarre solution to a simple problem. My DBAs would laugh at this request, rightly so.

Comment: @Pete855217 Your request is unusual, and the previous solution I offered is a quick fix which takes less than a minute to implement if your DBAs are any good. Anyways, what I put above should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I've gone for the solution you entered above: keeping a counter of the number of rows, and handling it that way, however in my world, a DBA won't change the database structure to help my coding style, and rightly so I believe.

Comment: That's true, but adding that extra column tends to help in more ways than you can imagine. For one, it tells you exactly which rows have been viewed/edited. Regardless, glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 2):

Write your query like

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

And try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Comment: My ans will give you the EOF for your record set

Comment: I dont think this is the solution. What he wants is to check whether the end of results array has reached.

Comment: End of the result means..??last record in that right..??I have done same thing....He can add his custome conditions

Comment: Yes RoyMJ that's right, the point was to check EOF status, without incrementing record pointer.  Gautam, your code simply gets one record, I'm not sure how it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_eof()` is deprecated. `mysql_errno()` or `mysql_error()` may be used instead.

`mysql_eof()` determines whether the last row of a result set has been read.

If you acquire a result set from a successful call to `mysql_store_result()`, the client receives the entire set in one operation. In this case, a NULL return from `mysql_fetch_row()` always means the end of the result set has been reached and it is unnecessary to call `mysql_eof()`. When used with `mysql_store_result(), mysql_eof()` always returns true.

Check out : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-eof.html for more details.

Comment: [All the mysql_* functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Comment: Thanks RoyMJ - my version of PHP is well past mysql_eof(), but I can try the mysql_error() method, although it's not optimum. The reason for wanting to do the logic the way I'm trying is that it keeps standard sequential file processing algorithms intact. Updating the algorithms is a vast task.